# Is there a way to relate $\operatorname{Var}(\theta)$ with $\operatorname{Var}(\operatorname{logit}(\theta))$?

Tags: bayesian

[image]

I am doing the above exercise in Jim ALbert's "Bayesian Computation with R", Chapter 5.

I have made a normal approximation of the paramater $\eta$, which is the logit of $\theta$.

I understand that for the problem (a), I can simply get a 95% credible interval for $\eta$, and them apply the inverse transformation to get the interval for $\theta$.

But I also want to use the approximated variance for $\eta$ (I got this from the normal approximation). I don't think I can simply apply the inverse transformation here. Is there a way to get the approximated variance for $\theta$ from what I have?

Comment: Many posts on site discuss this large sample approximation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to answer this I have to answer the whole question.  While I could do this pen and paper, I'm instead going to use R to compute the necessary quantities.

First, let's create a function for the log posterior.  We'll need the optima and the hessian in order to make the approximation.

```r
log_posterior <- function(eta){
  ll <- 125*log(2+plogis(eta)) - 39*log(1+exp(eta)) + 35*log(plogis(eta))
  return(ll)
}

# Optimize and compute the Hessian
quad_approx <- optim(par=0,
                     fn=log_posterior,
                     control=list(fnscale=-1),
                     method='L-BFGS-B', hessian = T)
```

Now that we've optimized this, let's plot the log posterior and the approximation

```r
eta <- seq(-3, 3, 0.001)
opt <- quad_approx$value
map <- quad_approx$par
hess <- as.numeric(abs(quad_approx$hessian))
norm_approx <- opt - hess/2*(eta-map)^2

plot(eta, log_posterior(eta), type='l')
lines(eta, norm_approx, col='red', lty='dashed')
legend(0, 0, legend=c("Log Posterior", "Normal Approximation"),
       col=c("black", "red"), lty=1:2, cex=1.2)
```

[image]

Cool, looks right.  Because the logit function is monotonic increasing, we can compute the quantiles on the scale of eta and simple transform the quantiles.

```r
proba_interval <- plogis(qnorm(c(0.025, 0.975), map, sqrt(1/hess)))
proba_interval
[1] 0.5200525 0.7176730
```

Great, so we have an approximate 95% credible interval from this computation.  The interval looks like

$$ \hat{\theta} \pm 2 \sigma $$

The length of the interval is

$$ L = (\hat{\theta} + 2\sigma) - (\hat{\theta} - 2\sigma) $$

so we can get the standard deviation (and eventually the variance) on the scale of theta by computing

$$\sigma = \dfrac{L}{4}$$

```r
L <- (proba_interval[2] - proba_interval[1])
sigma <- L/4
sigma
# 0.04940512
```

Ok, so $\sigma \approx 0.05$ which means the variance is approximately 0.0025.

Now we know where we are going.  We can use the Delta method to obtain an estimate of the variance on the scale of theta.  The Delta method states

$$ \operatorname{Var}(f(X)) \approx [f^\prime (\mu)]^2 \operatorname{Var}(X) $$

Here, $f$ is going to be the inverse logit function.  The derivative of the logit function has a very special property that $f^\prime(x) = f(x)(1-f(x))$ so we can leverage that in order not to do any tedious differentiation.  The computation of the asymptotic variance is then

```
theta_map <- plogis(map)
(theta_map*(1-theta_map))^2 * 1/hess
#0.00260476
```

Which is very close to our original calculation using the quantiles from the normal approximation.